# Query to Function (MSSQL) WHILE IF statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, func

I have

```
SELECT 
    Table.Citizen_id AS ID,
    Citizens.Name as Name,
    Citizens.City as City  
FROM Table 
INNER JOIN Citizens   
ON Table.Citizen_id = Citizens.id
GROUP BY Table.Citizen_id, Citizens.Name,Citizens.City;
```

I want create function Table_Citizens that have input param like Table.Citizen_id and output result for only this ID. 
But if Table.Citizen_id=0 then function should output data for all ID. And I want know how to exec this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Calls_ABCs(@ABC_id AS INT) 
RETURNS TABLE 
AS 
RETURN 
    SELECT 
    Calls.ABC_id AS ID,
    ABCs.Name as Name,
    ABCs.City as City, 
    COUNT(Calls.Call_start) as Count_Calls, 
    AVG(Calls.Duration) AS AVG_Call_duration,
    MAX(Calls.Duration) AS MAX_Call_duration,
    SUM(Calls.Duration) AS SUM_Call_duration,
    SUM(Calls.Cost) AS SUM_Call_cost,
    AVG(Calls.Cost) AS AVG_Calls_Cost,
FROM Calls 
INNER JOIN ABCs   
ON Calls.ABC_id = ABCs.id WHERE (@ABC_id=0 or Calls.ABC_id = @ABC_id) and  Calls.Call_Start > '2013-03-17'  GROUP BY Calls.ABC_id, ABCs.Name,ABCs.City;

GO
```

That does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.[udf_getCitizens]
(
      @Citizen_id INT
)
RETURNS @Result TABLE (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(50), City VARCHAR(50)) 
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @Result(ID, Name, City)
    SELECT DISTINCT
          ID = t.Citizen_id
        , c.Name
        , c.City
    FROM dbo.[Table] t 
    JOIN dbo.Citizens c ON t.Citizen_id = Citizens.id 
    WHERE @Citizen_Id = 0 OR t.Citizen_id = @Citizen_id

    RETURN

END
```

**Exec:**

```
DECLARE @ID INT
SELECT @ID = 5

SELECT *
FROM dbo.udf_getCitizens(@ID)
```

Comment: Thanks but IF @Citizen_id=0 dbo.[udf_getCitizens] should return ID = t.Citizen_id for all ID elsewhere only for selected ID.

Answer (score 2):

The query in your function would look like this:

```
SELECT 
    Table.Citizen_id AS ID,
    Citizens.Name as Name,
    Citizens.City as City  
FROM Table INNER JOIN
     Citizens   
     ON Table.Citizen_id = Citizens.id
where @Id = 0 or table.Citizen_id = @id
GROUP BY Table.Citizen_id, Citizens.Name,Citizens.City;
```

Often, this is indicates with a `NULL` value rather than `0`, because `NULL` works for all data types.  In that case:

```
where @Id is NULL or table.Citizen_id = @Id
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I rewrite my post. Maybe it was obscure. I need output f for all id when id = 0 and for current id elsewhere.

Comment: @user2377214 . . . That is what this query does.

Comment: Thanks again but this don`t work on SQL SERVER 2012. 0 returns void. DECLARE @ID INT
SELECT @ID = 5

SELECT *
FROM dbo.udf_getCitizens(@ID)

Comment: @user2377214 . . . That is presumably because the record with id 5 has no records after '2013-03-17'.  Does the query return anything when you hardcode "5" and run it outside the function?

Comment: "where @Id is NULL or table.Citizen_id = @Id". I forgot how this trick  called? And why it works?

Comment: I unterstood how it works with all selected ID`s but how it output only current ID?

Comment: No need explanations. I understood. Thanks.

Comment: This works with id=0 not with IS NULL. I assume that when equality appears "=0" return true. I am wrong? But thi is do not works with IS NULL

Comment: I thinks that is normal because NULL not euals '0". But it just my thoughts.

Comment: When where @ABC_id=0 is selected it @ABC_id=0 everywhere,

Comment: I can replace '0' with '5' and it works. But NULL IS space, no "0" or something numeral.

Comment: @user2377214 . . . If you want it to work with NULL or 0 meaning everything, then do `@Id is null or @Id = 0 or table.Citizen_id = @id`.